# Finding the posterior distribution of a Bayesian analysis prior

Tags: self-study, bayesian, prior, posterior

I have a prior distribution $f(x)=\pi cos(\pi x) $ where $x$ is the probability of getting tails in a coin toss.
Should a coin toss result in tails, how would this be reflected in the posterior distribution?

Would the posterior distribution simply be $f(x)=\pi cos(\pi/2) $, as $P(x)=1/2$?

Thank you!

Comment: Is $x$ in $[0,0.5]$?

Comment: Hi gunes, $x$ is in [0,1]

Comment: Then, $f(x)$ is not a valid PDF, since it is negative after $0.5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your prior is made valid, e.g. as in your comment, $f(x)=\pi/2\sin(\pi x)$, you can find the posterior via Bayes Rule ($D$ denotes your experiment):
$$f(x|D)=\frac{p(D|x)f(x)}{p(D)}\propto p(D|x)f(x)=x\pi/2\sin(\pi x)$$
$p(D|x)=x$ because we have only one toss and it is tails. Finally, we need to normalize this expression by calculating the following integral and dividing the expression by it:
$$Z=\pi/2\int_0^1 x\sin(\pi x)dx\rightarrow f(x|D)=\frac{1}{Z}x\pi/2\sin(\pi x)$$

Comment: Hi gunes, thank you so much! If this were two tails, how would the $p(D|x)$ function change?

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask you one more question regarding this.. in order to calculate posterior probability, would the function need to be integrated at a certain value?

Comment: You should just calculate $Z$ above. I didn't get what you mean by *integrating at a certain value*.

Comment: @Sarina if it were two tails: $p(D|x)=x^2$

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)\propto x\,\sin \pi x\Bbb 1_{(0,1)}(x)$, then
$$\int_0^1 x\,\sin \pi x\,\text{d}x=\pi^{-2}\int_0^\pi x\,\sin x\,\text{d}x=\pi^{-2}\underbrace{\left[-x\cos x\right]_0^\pi}_{=\pi-0}+\pi^{-2}\underbrace{\int_0^\pi \cos x\,\text{d}x}_{=0}=\pi^{-1}$$
therefore
$$f(x)=\pi x \sin \pi x$$